# Option to use the flutter web build javascript file and parse it through astro?

Tags: flutter, astrojs

I would like to serve only HTML to my customers without Javascript. The flutter build for web releases one flutter file. Would it be possible to somehow get this parsed by astro so only html is served? Would this make sense at all?

Comment: No - it makes no sense, since the Flutter Web UI is built dynamically by the Javascript (compiled from your Dart and Flutter framework).

Comment: yeah but asto takes javascript and makes html out of it